# To reinstall Indigo to Jade

Tags: gazebo, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, ROS community!

I would like to clarify or to get additional information about Gazebo version and ROS distribution. My current versions are Gazebo 2.2.6, Indigo ROS distribution and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I would like to build a world model by the Building editor, but it is possible only for Gazebo 5+. When I read about the [combination of versions](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions), I figured out that I need to upgrade ROS from Indigo to Jade. My questions are :

1. Should I delete completely Indigo and install Jade after?
2. Is there any tutorial how to upgrade the distribution?

I was searching the ROS forum before I asked the question and I found [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/217970/ros-jade-and-gazebo-50-migration-problem/) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/211291/ros-indigo-re-installation-problem/). But, I wanted to ask you before I will begin to install it.

Pls, give me an advice how to do it right in my situation, because It is complicated process to change the distribution.
And, I guess, I will need time to set up my packages again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226328/to-reinstall-indigo-to-jade/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just run the install instructions for jade, no need to remove indigo. Files will be installed in /opt, indigo in a folder called indigo, jade in one called jade.

Edit your .bashrc file to source jade rather than indigo and it will find the files there. If you need to move back to indigo just edit the .bashrc file again to go back

You will need to install any packages you need on top of the main install again, and change the Gazebo version

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on 2016-02-12**:
Thank you for your reply! I have installed ROS Jade and Gazebo )